# Cookie Restriction Mode Translation

Tags: magento-1.8, cookie, cms-block, bug

With latest release, CE 1.8.1 `cookie_restriction_notice_block` went to `before_body_end` in layout (/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml). But users don’t realize about that notice nor that they are expected to allow cookies.

I used this code to easily unset `global_cookie_notice block` from `before_body_end` and set it in `after_body_start` in layout file `local.xml` in my theme:

```
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>global_cookie_notice</name></action>    
    </reference>

    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="page/html_cookieNotice" name="global_cookie_notice" as ="global_cookie_notice" template="page/html/cookienotice.phtml" before="-" />
    </reference>`
```

However, I can’t figure out how to translate for different store views. Changing text as usual in CMS block in the admin (`cookie_restriction_notice_block`) for different store views didn't work for me.

How can I translate `cookie_restriction_notice_block` for different store views?

Comment: Where is the text located. Is it in cookienotice.phtml or a static block?

Comment: Text is in a static block. I created different versions per store view as usual, but text is not translated (the ALLOW button is translated via .csv). I see COOKIE_RESTRICTION_NOTICE_CMS_BLOCK_IDENTIFIER is set in cookie.php, but can't figure out how to make it work

Answer (score 12):

in app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/CookieNotice.php:

```
$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($blockIdentifier, 'identifier');
```

Before loading the block, you should set Store ID:

```
$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($blockIdentifier, 'identifier');
```

You can use your local app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/CookieNotice.php

Answer (score 2):

This block is installed by the CMS module to the default store scope in *`app/code/core/Mage/Cms/data/cms_setup/data-upgrade-1.6.0.0.1-1.6.0.0.2.php`*:

```
$content = "<p>This website requires cookies to provide all of its features. For more " .
    "information on what data is contained in the cookies, please see our " .
    "<a href=\"{{store direct_url=\"privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode\"}}\">Privacy Policy page</a>. " .
    "To accept cookies from this site, please click the Allow button below.</p>";

$cmsBlock = array(
    'title'         => 'Cookie restriction notice',
    'identifier'    => 'cookie_restriction_notice_block',
    'content'       => $content,
    'is_active'     => 1,
    'stores'        => 0
);

Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setData($cmsBlock)->save();
```

The translated versions you are trying to create in the admin *will* work as long as they are limited to the appropriate store scope.

**NB: The parameters of the data load can be debugged in `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Block::_getLoadSelect()`.**

Comment: I just tried in a clean CE 1.8.1 install, cookies restriction mode on, added a store view, translated the static block with same identifier and assigned new store view. Then, in frontend switched view and text is not translated.

Comment: Did you assign the original block to the English store?

Comment: In this clean install i have Main Website/Main Website Store/ and two store views for Main Website Store, Default Store View and Castellano (new store view created). In static blocks, I have the default - (Title)Cookie restriction notice, (ID) cookie_restriction_notice, (Store View) Default - and the newly created - (Title)Nota Cookies, (ID) cookie_restriction_notice, (Store View) Castellano. Both are enabled, and switching store view in frontend doesn't help. i never had issues translating static blocks, also older versions worked properly if I am not wrong.

Comment: Something else is going on, because the CMS blocks are explicitly loaded based on store scope. Can you check in the `cms_block_store` table for the `store_id` value of the English version?

Comment: thanks for your time. In this fresh install now, block_id is 2 for english version and 3 for Spanish version in cms_block_table and crossing with cms_block_store table, I get block_id 2 (EN) shown in store_id 1 and block_id 3 (ES) shown in store_id 2.

Comment: Added a note about debugging.

Comment: We need to advance on all other fronts now. I will try to come this in few days, and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

> Something else is going on, because the CMS blocks are explicitly loaded based on store scope. Can you check in the `cms_block_store` table for the `store_id` value of the English version? – benmarks♦ Feb 19 '14 at 13:12

No, CMS blocks are **not** loaded explicitly on store scope. The `load()` methods ends in a `fetchRow($select)` call, that just returns the **first row** (see `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::load()`). In this case the block added from install script.

The `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Block::_getLoadSelect()` method needs a store ID set to join `cms_block_store` table. Without setting store ID `$object->getStoreId()` is `NULL` ...

```
/**
 * Retrieve select object for load object data
 *
 * @param string $field
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param Mage_Cms_Model_Block $object
 * @return Zend_Db_Select
 */
protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{
    $select = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);

    if ($object->getStoreId()) {
        $stores = array(
            (int) $object->getStoreId(),
            Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID,
        );

        $select->join(
            array('cbs' => $this->getTable('cms/block_store')),
            $this->getMainTable().'.block_id = cbs.block_id',
            array('store_id')
        )->where('is_active = ?', 1)
        ->where('cbs.store_id in (?) ', $stores)
        ->order('store_id DESC')
        ->limit(1);
    }

    return $select;
}
```

... a bug, that still exists :( Think https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18380/46249 is correct ...