# Magento EU Cookie law restriction block not loaded per store id? cookie_restriction_notice_block

Tags: store-view, cookie, blocks

Magento EU Cookie law restriction block not loaded per store id? cookie_restriction_notice_block

Hi, we are using default Magento EU Cookie law restriction block and I had set a block in CMS/BLOCKS where I would normally do it. Then I make that block member of the relevant storeviews.

However I am now seeing that the Magento EU Cookie law restriction block does not seem to respect the fact that we have two versions for every language.

Problem: It keeps showing the one version with the highest ID (and not the one belonging to our language specific store)

So essentially: store 1 EN => should use cookie_restriction_notice_block that is enabled in english store & 
store 2 DE => should use cookie_restriction_notice_block that is enabled in german store

But all stores show the same english store version? (which is strange because from the german store perspective this block is not enabled)

Experiences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/CookieNotice.php`

```
$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($blockIdentifier, 'identifier');
```

Before loading the block, you should set Store ID:

```
$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($blockIdentifier, 'identifier');
```

You can use your local `app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/CookieNotice.php` Hope it helps someone

Source:
[Cookie Restriction Mode Translation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15280/cookie-restriction-mode-translation)

Comment: Is it not a bug which should be reported?

Comment: TIPP: If *using local* is deativated for security reasons in *local.xml* it is not working. Just a hint. Chaning core and fixing after updates is your way.
<disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>